# Bounty dialog covered by answer box on mobile

Tags: bug, status-completed, bounties, mobile-web

While trying to place a bounty on mobile, I was blocked by the answer box:

[image]

(Android 2.2.1 in built browser, on [this page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/180850/216955) )

Could this be fixed with some `z-index` magic?

Comment: You're doomed..

Comment: Can be reproduced with plain old desktop Chrome using the mobile view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been fixed and will be available in the next deployment (`rev 2245` on meta and `rev 1606` on the network).