# SO mobile site "Your Answer" textbox appears on top of flag dialog

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, mobile-web, flag-dialog

The "Your Answer" textbox seems to be eating the flagging dialog as shown in Figure A.

[image]

Comment: Because of how chrome for iOS works, this should happen in Safari as well. I would suggest removing the browser specific title. Note: not happening in the iOS 7 beta, however.

Comment: That's odd as I'm currently running iOS7 beta (note the reception dots as opposed to bars).  Should I just say iOS or should I say WebKit based browsers then?

Comment: Well the way iOS 7 was designed (without breaking NDAs and such) if an app wasn't compiled under Xcode 5, it runs as an iOS 6 app, meaning it uses an older version of WebKit, with all it's quirks, AFAIK.

Comment: Oh, I apologize, I misunderstood which beta (iOS vs chrome) you were referring to.

Comment: This problem appears to also [appear on android](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197115/flagging-dialogue-obscured-by-rectangle-on-some-mobile-browsers) on both chrome and the default android browser

Comment: Sounds like missing/wrong `z-index` in the mobile theme CSS file.

Comment: Why has this not been fixed yet?

Comment: works for me on N5230 (S60) / Opera Mobile

Comment: @Jan are you sure, it only really occures on questions without answers (and on the second page; eg off topic because...)

Comment: This is a problem with the flagging dialogue but not with the (near identical) closing dialogue

Comment: @ElefantPhace bug reports can sit idle for years, this one isn't that critical. Worst case use the full site theme.

Comment: Also happens on WP.

Comment: Also on Firefox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed yesterday and is available since `rev 2245` on meta and `rev 1606` on the network as part of [this bugfix](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181741/bounty-dialog-covered-by-answer-box-on-mobile/231611#231611).

Comment: If same bug then it's a dupe. :)

Comment: same fix, different bug

Comment: Oh, oops. Will retract my close vote then.

Answer (score 2):

While this is far from a solution; a usable workaround to this problem is to ensure the view is scrolled up as much as possible when you click on your flagging options (so what you click is at the very bottom of the screen). This ensures that the stuck text box is far away from anything you might want to click on the next screen.

Rotating the screen from portrait to landscape (after opening the dialogue) can also shift the text box around; potentially allowing the dialogue to be revealed.

Comment: Not true. If the post is fairly long you lose the ability to scroll and the dialog is forced to the bottom especially after you choose a reason that had more selections

Comment: It does depend heavily on the situated, it is an imperfect work around to be sure! But by manipulation of the position ive been able to flag so far