# Flagging dialogue obscured by rectangle on (some) mobile browsers

Tags: bug, flags, mobile-web, flag-dialog

When flagging a question on the standard browser on android and chrome on android on a galaxy S3 the "second page" of the flagging dialogue is obscured by a white rectangle (see screen shot). <sub>(However the near identical close dialogue does not have the same problems)</sub>

In this example I have flagged a question clicking "This question should be closed for another reason" being brought to the screen shot page where some of the options are obscured. The bug is not specific to the "other reasons" page and all second pages of the flagging dialogue show this problem.

[image]

The problem did not occure on dolphine mobile browser.

#### Workaround

The white rectangle appears to be your own answer box getting "stuck" to the dialogue. As such you can avoid it by ensuring your view is as scrolled up as possible (so what you're clicking is at the very bottom of the screen. This ensures that your answer box is out of the way when it gets stuck

Comment: @michaelb958 It does seem identical.  Oddly ive only been experiencing this for a couple of weeks on a (afaik) unchanged system and yet that bug seems to have been ongoing since 2012

Comment: I went 90% of the way to voting to closing this myself, but the "on chrome for iOS" gives me pause, would it be apropriate to edit out the "on chrome for iOS" on the other question; making it a true duplicate? The comments there seem to be talking about some quite iOS specific stuff