# Flag dialogue appears under the answer textarea on mobile

Tags: bug, flags, mobile-web

When opening the flag dialogue on the mobile version of the site and choosing the "it should be closed for another reason" option, the flag dialogue appears underneath the answer textarea making some of the flag options inaccessible. This happens to me using the native Android browser on Android 4.1.2. I don't have any other mobile devices to test with however.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: @Marc-Andre That's for iOS; this question is asking about Android.

Comment: @gparyani this question for android http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197115/flagging-dialogue-obscured-by-rectangle-on-some-mobile-browsers was closed as a duplicate of the iOS one. I just applied the same logic.

Comment: Thanks @AlEverett, mobile browsers are not conducive to good spelling

Comment: This is definitely a new problem (probably same route cause as the iOS one but new event) as two of these (one mine) have come in today

Comment: @marc-andre should the iOS question be edited to be more general in that case?

Comment: @RichardTingle I think it would be a good idea since it does not seems to only be a bug on iOS and the bug looks exactly the same to me.