# Mobile site flag popup box getting blocked

Tags: support, bug, mobile-web, flag-dialog

The mobile site flag question popup gets blocked by the answer text view. Unable to view and select few options. This happens for a question with no answers or comments.

My device information

- Browser: Google chrome 29.0.1547.72
- Device: Galaxy Nexus
- Android OS: 4.3.0
- Webkit version 537.36

I've also checked this with Firefox browser and observed similar issue.

[image]

Comment: Its annoying isn't it, see [SO mobile site “Your Answer” textbox appears on top of flag dialog on chrome for iOS](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196683/so-mobile-site-your-answer-textbox-appears-on-top-of-flag-dialog-on-chrome-for) for the original (iOS) and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197115/flagging-dialogue-obscured-by-rectangle-on-some-mobile-browsers for the android version for the adroid specific version

Comment: @RichardTingle Yeah a bit. Need to reach out for the computer to flag. :)

Comment: with a bit of clever positioning you can work around this, see my answer on http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196683/so-mobile-site-your-answer-textbox-appears-on-top-of-flag-dialog-on-chrome-for

Comment: @RichardTingle Was just going through the post. Any official word on this yet?

Comment: Not even a peep i'm afraid. I started a bounty in hope of getting somewhere but the chrome iOS people seem to have had this problem since mid 2012