# Add Week and Month tabs to all Stack Exchange sites

Tags: feature-request

I find the Week and Month tabs on the home page of stackoverflow.com to be indispensable for how I use the site. In particular, most of the time that I browse the site I want to find interesting questions and answers so that I can learn from them. However, I am not able to spend much time on the site so I browse it once or twice a week for a relatively brief time. The Week and Month tabs allow me to quickly find interesting content that I would not have time to find by browsing through thousands of questions.

Now, I understand that these tabs do not necessarily show the most interesting questions but instead show the most popular questions, which might be the questions that have been bumped several times, received an answer from a high profile member of the community, or are about a common as opposed to novel issue. These tabs are not perfect; nonetheless, they go a long way toward helping me quickly pick interesting questions out of the vast sea of noise.

Unfortunately, many Stack Exchange sites, such as mathoverflow.net, programmers.stackexchange.com and politics.stackexchange.com, don't have these tabs. Fortunately, I did notice that math.stackexchange.com recently acquired them so perhaps there is already a push to add them throughout Stack Exchange. If not, I kindly request addition of these tabs to the sites that don't have them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Week and Month tabs are [only visible when you are logged in](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180850/hot-and-week-tabs-not-shown-to-non-logged-in-users-except-on-so). You don't have an account on any of the sites you mentioned, so that's why you don't see the tabs.

This is what I see when I log into Programmers.SE:

> [image: week and month tabs, if you couldn't already guess]

Conversely, I do not have an account on Math.SE, so I do not see the tabs that you have recently noticed.

Comment: Interesting, I never noticed. This behavior is not intuitive, especially because stackoverflow.com always shows the Week and Month tabs. Is there a reason for this behavior?

Comment: @jef: Explained by SE staff [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180850/hot-and-week-tabs-not-shown-to-non-logged-in-users-except-on-so). Short version: Non-logged-in users didn't know what they were for and never clicked them.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that this can be kind of hidden sometimes. You have to click the icon for name of the exchange and then you have access to those links. For whatever reason, these links are not accessible if "Questions" is clicked.

[image]

Comment: The reason I didn't see the Top Questions page is that I wasn't logged in, as mmyers mentioned. But as an aside, it is unintuitive that clicking Questions doesn't show all options for viewing questions.

Comment: @jef Related bit from Meta.P.SE: [Why does the questions 'tab' have different sub tabs than the main page?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6749/why-does-the-questions-tab-have-different-sub-tabs-than-the-main-page) about how the subtle / unintuitive 'main page' tab is, well, subtle or unintuitive.